# Javascript array access(with string literal as key) - space complexity

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, heap-memory

Sample object:

```
const myArray = {'attributes':{ 'fullName': 'Foo Bar'};
```

During code review, I found that one key(string type) was being used to access the object in multiple functions.
Now my question is, should we access the object directly by using the string literal as key, e.g. `myArray['attributes']['fullName']`
or use a constant instead, like :

```
const ATTRIBUTES = 'attributes';
const FULLNAME = 'fullName';
someVar = myArray[ATTRIBUTES][FULLNAME];
```

According to my knowledge, the latter approach is better because it reserves only one memory block.
But my friend had a different opinion, he told if we use the string literal for key, then it won't have any impact on memory.

Now, I am confused and don't know which approach is better. 
Could anyone help me understanding which one is better with explanation?

Comment: How much memory are you working with here? The impact of this is likely to be _very_ small. My guess is that the second option would indeed use less memory, as you're defining the string a single time, rather than in multiple places, but I'd also guess that javascript is fairly sensible about disposing of memory used to access a key on an object

Comment: Memory on that scale is superfluous unless you are in 80s.

Comment: On a further note, I see no good reason to close this question; whilst it may _seem_ irrelevant at this moment in time, it is a valid question, and I can't see how on earth it is opinion based

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will make no performance difference. In my opinion the second option is less readable too.

Answer (score 0):

I would take

```
myArray.attributes.fullName
```

because it shows the compilter to use a constant to a value, instead of using brwacket notation where the structure is aimed for dynamic use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the memory, and I'm using the first option, but in case of the key changing I'll have to modify it at several places rather than one so for code retake it's not so good